# Are git tags merged?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-tag

Lets assume we are developing with git and pull requests and we have :

1. a master branch
2. a release/1.... branch
   and for every hotfix or feature there is also a branch which is merged into the starting branch after the pull request is accepted.

So my questions are:

1. If the release branch contains Tags and if the release branch is merged into the master after the last released version of release/1.x.y, are the tags also merged?
2. And for long term support my question is:

   Let's assume somebody wants to check out the state of tag 1.1.1 in 10 years.
   Is it possible to check out this tagged commit if the release branch was deleted but was merged into the master and we have the master ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The literal answer to the question in your subject line—*Are git tags merged?*—is "no", but that's not an interesting answer, because neither are *branch names*.  Merges, in Git, work through *commits*.

The diagram you posted is not bad, but it has a few things in it that are misleading.  Here are some notes about it:

- The arrows in it point forwards.  Git does not work forwards; Git works backwards.  Usually this doesn't matter too much, but in terms of *finding* commits, it's important.
- The round circles represent commits.  This is all fine.
- Some commits are *merge commits* and some commits are *ordinary commits*.  In this case, all the purple `feature/*` commits are ordinary, as is the single `bugfix/bug-1` red one.  Most of the yellow and green commits are merge commits.

  Since the diagram has the arrows the wrong way around—it has them forwards instead of Git's backwards-ness—you can tell which commits are merge commits because they have more than one arrow coming in to them.  Had the arrows been drawn correctly, i.e., backwards, a merge commit would be any commit with two or more arrows coming *out* of it.
- Branch names and tag names simply identify *one* commit.  The diagram is highly misleading here because it puts the names `master` and `release/1.0.0` on the left.  If these are branch names, they really should be on the *right*, pointing to the *last commit in that branch*.

  Git makes use of the arrows coming out of each commit—that is, the arrows that *would be* coming out of each commit, if the arrows had been drawn correctly—to work *backwards*.  Hence a *branch name* **always** identifies the *last* commit in the branch.  That means the name points to the last commit in the chain.

A tag name, like a branch name, simply points directly to one commit.  The key differences between tag names and branch names include the fact that **a branch name moves over time**, so that as you add new commits, the name continues to point to the *last* commit.  So if we have a tiny repository with just three commits in it, and we use uppercase letters (rather than round circles) to stand in for these commits, we can draw them like this:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

The name `master` points to the last commit, `C`.  Commit `C` itself points to earlier commit `B`, which points to very-first commit `A`.  (Since `A` is that very-first commit, it just doesn't point anywhere, which is how Git knows to stop traversing.)

To add a new commit—let's call it `D`—Git writes out the new commit so that it points back to existing commit `C`, which used to be the last commit on the branch.  Then Git writes `D`'s actual hash ID, whatever that is, into the *name* `master`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
```

If a tag name is made to point to one of these commits, that tag name stays where it is:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <--master
            ^
            |
         tag:v11
```

When we add some new commits we get:

```
A <-B <-C <-D <-E <-F   <--master
            ^
            |
         tag:v11
```

The tag name has not moved, and should never move.  (You can manually "move" one, by deleting it and creating another one with the same name, or using one of the force options, but in general you should not do this.)

> Is it possible to check out this tagged commit if the release branch was deleted ...

Certainly.  Branch names, tag names, and other names serve to locate one specific commit.  You can go directly to that commit, using that name.  The commit itself will be retained in that Git repository as long as the name itself continues to exist.

Having found some commit—usually, by a name—Git can use the internal arrows embedded inside each commit to move backwards through history.  This means that if there's a name for commit `D`, as in the drawing above, Git can use `D` to find `C`, which it can use to find `B`, which it can use to find `A`.  These four commits will therefore remain in this repository, because `D` is find-able.

Note that the name `master` locates commit `F`, which means commit `F` is retained.  Commit `F` locates commit `E`, which locates `D`, and so on; so these commits will also be retained.  There are therefore two names that mean that `D`-and-earlier must be retained.  Deleting either of these names reduces the number of `D`-retaining-names to 1, but `D` must still be retained.  If the name we delete is `master`, though, commit `F` is no longer required to be retained.  If commit `F` is thrown out, that means commit `E` is no longer find-able either, and commit `E` can be thrown out as well.

If we add another name to find `F`, it becomes safe, in some sense, to delete the name `master`.  Deleting the name `master` will, in effect, "forget" that the *last* commit in `master` was, at this time, commit `F`, but commit `F` will be find-able through some *other* name and therefore won't be thrown out.

Note that any merge commit has two (or more<sup>1</sup>) arrows coming out of it.  If that merge commit is find-able, the arrows coming from it retain all the earlier commits down each of those paths.  So once you have merged some branch-tip commit, as identified by some branch name, into some other branch whose name you intend to keep, it's safe to delete the merged branch's name: you won't be able to find that tip commit *directly*, but you can find it *indirectly* by finding the *merge commit* that has it as one of its extra *parent commit* hash IDs.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls this kind of merge, one that has more than two "legs" coming out of it, an *octopus merge*.  This may be why GitHub use [octocat](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=octocat) as their logo.

Answer (score 7):

> 1.) *If the release branch contains Tags and if the release branch is merged into the master after the last released version of
> release/1.x.y, are the tags also merged?*

Tags are not merged, commits (tagged or not) are.

> 2.) *And for long term support my question is: Lets assume somebody wants to check out the state of tag 1.1.1 in 10 years. Is it possible
> to check out this tagged commit if the release branch was deleted but
> was merged into the master and we have the master ?*

Yes it is not only possible, but the very purpose of tags. Tags are permanent references to specific commits, so these commits will remain accessible for inspection later on, **even if** they're not merged into anything.

Comment: Is this not paradox? I do not have the branch with the taged commit and Tags are not merged into the master but after 10 years i can still checkout this tag

Comment: A paradox? How? This is the purpose of tags : putting an unmovable reference on some state. Branches, in the other hand, come and go. If a commit isn't referenced neither by a tag or a branch any more, yes, it will become eligible for garbage collection. Tags prevent that.

Comment: This is my understanding as well, but for some reason, AVH git-flow is creating commits with messages like `Merge Tag '1.x.y'`, and I don't understand why it is there in addition to the `Merge branch 'hotfix/1.x.y' into master`. anyone know why these seemingly superfluous commits are being created?

Answer (score 3):

The answers are correct, but a little bit complex. Here is a short answer:

> If the release branch contains Tags and if the release branch is merged into the master after the last released version of release/1.x.y, are the tags also  merged?

Tags have not much to do with the branches. They only point to a specific commit - it dosen't matter in which branch the commit is.
So yes, the tags are still available after the merge.

> And for long term support my question is:
>
> Let's assume somebody wants to check out the state of tag 1.1.1 in 10 years. Is it possible to check out this tagged commit if the release branch was deleted but was merged into the master and we have the master ?

Yes.

Comment: "*They only point to a specific commit*" -> Exactly as branches do. Tags and branches are not that different. Tags are basically unmovable branches.

Answer (score 2):

If you just merge development branch to Master you dont lose tags. Difference between tags and branch it's that tags are marker to  specific commit (tag isn't moved with next commit. In turn branches are moved with every commit). So if you make merge operation, and you push commits with tags, you could go back to the tags/commits with tags.

You just must remembet to push your tags to remote repository.
[Example merge branches with tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMrO.jpg)